# Divide image into 8x8 block : Python

Tags: python, image-processing

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as numpy
import cv2

windowsize_r = 8
windowsize_c = 8

img = cv2.imread('image test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
for r in range(0,gray.shape[0] - windowsize_r, windowsize_r):
for c in range(0,gray.shape[0] - windowsize_c, windowsize_c):
    window = gray[r:r+windowsize_r,c:c+windowsize_c]
    hist = numpy.histogram(window,bins=256)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if k == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am trying to divide am image into 8x8 blocks. My image size is 320x240. So at the end there should be 1200 blocks.my code is not showing any error but nothing is observed as output. Can anyone suggest a better solution

Answer (score 0):

you need to use cv2.imshow to actually show the patch before calling waitKey. eg:

```
cv2.imshow('wind',window)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I tried this comment in return an error is found "mat is not a numerical tuple"

Comment: @user2231696 sorry I put the wrong variable in imshow. you can plot the image region- not the histogram. If you want to plot the histogram use matplotlib!

Comment: thanks for the answer. But plot will be plotting the histogram. I need to see the grey levels of each block.and one more doubt if we give such an command , will it plot the complete 1200 blocks. I just want to see only one block

Comment: the hist function in matplotlib.pyplot is definitely what you want. It's up to you to figure out where it goes...

Comment: @Aswathy i have to agree with John Greenall here. matplotlib is a very versatile pltting lib that combines well with numpy. numpy.histogram() returns a histogram object, not the plot. Matplotlib will plot this for you! (doc are fantastic in figuring out how)